# Check the time stored in the DB, then make sure its 15 min later before running a update task

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to stop people from constantly syncing/updating items in the DB as this could cause potential problems.  I have a time the last sync/update occured which is stored in the DB.  What I need to do is disable the user from initiating another update/sync until 15 minutes has passed since the last update/sync.

How would i go about doing this?

Update: for some reason i am getting the error "A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type" on DateTime lastUpdate. Any ideas why this could be?

```
 DataDataContext dc = new DataDataContext();

        DateTime lastUpdate = from t in dc.Settings
                              where t.id == 1
                              select t.lastSync;


        if ((DateTime.Now - lastUpdate).TotalMinutes >= 15)
        {

        }
        else { }
```

Update: Sorted, i missed off the (); of the datacontext!! *facepalm*

Final Update: All fixed and working! Many thanks for all your help, for the ones who think this "smells fishy" or "is bad" then here is what i did!!

```
DateTime lastUpdate = (from t in dc.Settings
                               where t.id == 1
                               select t.lastSync).Single();


        if ((DateTime.Now - lastUpdate).TotalMinutes >= 15)
        {
            syncbuttons.Visible = false;
        }
        else { syncbuttons.Visible = true; }
```

Now please explain what is so suspect about what i am trying to do? Stopping users from hammering a database? What if i have 30 users attempting to update/sync. Would not be that good would it!

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a brute-force kind of fix? It smells a little bit bad to me...

Comment: no its for a web app i am developing. All i want to know is how to check the time, add 15 mins onto it then enable the sync button to allow users to update/sync. I am unsure how this would be a brute-force fix? what ever one of those is.

Comment: So you're going to let the end user load a web page and alter it but tell them that they can't save their altered data until time X? I don't think you should do that on the server side, you should do it on the client side (javascript). But I agree with @Icarus: something smells funny here.

Comment: i really do not understand what "smells funny"?! I am doing this in the code behind. All i am doing is hiding the sync button that hits a web service and calls products from our main DB, then updates a 2nd DB we use for Amazon - imagine this being done constantly by 30 users?!. whats so bad about that?

Comment: Maybe the end users shouldn't be allowed to update the secondary db. Why not have that be an automated process that runs several times a day, at night maybe? Don't be combative, there's a lot of people here that probably know more than you do about building good web apps. I have no idea if I'm one of them.

Comment: The other issue here is that the web page is static but the time is dynamic: if the user _can_ update the secondary db they won't know until they refresh the web page. From a UX perspective, that's annoying.

Comment: The plan is to have it all moved to automated once the main app is completed. Not sure how yet. This is just as a manual thing for now, which only admins will be allowed access too. But its just a precaution to stop things being hammered. The reason i got 'combative' was because it felt like you both were accusing me of doing something dodgey, when it was quite innocent.

Comment: The page simply has a button on it saying Sync. That is it. nothing else :) it just calls a service, which as i said updated the 2nd DB we use for amazon with the correct stock/details etc the actual page does nothing else.

Comment: Well it is dodgy if you plan on keeping it around. If it's just a stopgap until a SQL Job can be written, then sure, it works.

Comment: lol maybe i never explained the concept in the first place. Its main use atm is to make sure the web service is working. And test the other method in the web service so i can update stock levels etc. nothing more :) I agree having it automated would be far better, and less reason for user error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime lastUpdate = ...;  // Retrieve from DB
TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - lastUpdate;
if (elapsed.TotalMinutes >= 15)
{
}
```

Or, in one line:

```
if ((DateTime.Now - lastUpdate).TotalMinutes >= 15)
```

Comment: DateTime lastUpdate = from t in dc.Settings select t.lastSync; is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I didn't realize you were also unsure how to read the value from the DB.  It depends on your DB schema.  I don't know in your example what `dc` is.  I'm also not that familiar with LINQ.  It certainly looks about right.  Did you try it?  Are you familiar with how to use the debugger to trace through your code and inspect your variable values?

Comment: yeah, i am just getting an error about converting to DateTime, even though the field is a datetime field!

dc is my datacontext, which is setting up my database connection.

Comment: What type does it say it is that can't be converted to DateTime?

Comment: its ok sorted that issue now. Next its saying "A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type"

Comment: On what line?  None of the code we've discussed uses the `new` keyword.

Comment: this is the line where i connect to the DB to get the datetime! lol

Answer (score 1):

```
if (lastUpdateTime.AddMinutes(15)<DateTime.Now)
{
    // do update
}
```

Comment: I am guessing the lastUpdateTime will be what i call from the DB?

Comment: how do i get the date out the DB? i seem to be having issues :S `DateTime lastUpdate = from t in dc.Settings
                                  where t.id == 1
                                  select t.lastSync;` is returning "A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type"

Comment: I think I would do it like this:

`DateTime lastUpdate = (DateTime)(from t in dc.Settings where t.id == 1 select t).Single().lastSync);`

This is assuming that your lastSync field in the DB is the correct data type.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that causes the error is that your linq expression returns an (IQuerryable) collecton, but you are trying to assign/cast it to a DateTime.

Try using

```
        DateTime lastUpdate = (from t in dc.Settings
                     where t.id == 1
                     select t.lastSync).Single();
```

Regarding the Db sync; I'm no DB expert, but I don't think that 30 connections should be considered anywhere near a heavy load. If it is then you are much better of if you optimize the the db and transactions.

Disabling a Sync-button won't stop users from hitting the reload-button, which in turn probably will generate a lot more traffic than a custom tailored refresh procedure.

And even if you fix that, what if your user-base increases to a point where you get 30 connections a second without people hammering on a sync button.

So my suggestion is that you go back and see if you can minimize the impact of the syncing instead. One way might be to put a timestamp on the records that you are fetching. Than index that column so it will be fast on lookups and have the db check if any rows are newer than the users las sync.

Just making your application unresponsive or lagging (in the eyes of the user) should not be considered a viable solution.

At least that's how I would approach the problem.

Comment: @thatuxguy Thats good, I also updated my answer with some thoughts on why preventing updates might be a bad idea.